# LIST.count() in Python

Tags: python

Dears,
please need help in count method
if

```
LIST=[0,0.0,False,[],(),{},1,1.1,True]
```

and if using `.count` and searching on `0` or `0.0` or `False`

--- `LIST.count(0)` or `LIST.count(0.0)` or `LIST.count(False)` ---

return 3 only not 6 , while there are another 3 elements Consider as `False`: `[]`,`()`,`{}` as below `bool` Function

if we used `bool([])` or `bool(())` or `bool({})` to know its Boolean Value will Return `False`

also I Tried to Check

```
print([] == False) | print(() == False) | print({} == False)
```

will return `False` not `True`

Comment: they are falsey values not `False` (0 and 1 can be directly interpreted as `False` and `True`), you can do sth like `print([bool(item) for item in LIST].count(False))`

Comment: Do you want to count falsey or non-falsey elements? In either case, `list.count()` is not the proper tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what your final goal is, but looking for `zero` (False) using the `.count` method, you can create another list by transforming the original elements to boolean

```
>>> lst = [0, 0.0, False, [], (), {}, 1, 1.1, True] 
>>> l = [bool(el) for el in lst]
>>> l.count(0)
6
>>> l.count(False)
6
```

If you want to count both True and False equivalents you can rely on the standard library using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> import collections as co
>>> c = co.Counter(map(bool, lst))
>>> c[False]
6
>>> c[True]
3
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun iterator way to count false elements:

```
false = 0
it = iter(LIST)
while not all(it):
    false += 1
```

Or a boring normal way:

```
false = sum(1 for x in LIST if not x)
```